# What to do when Installation can't find a library or program?

Tags: installation, apt-get

I am a pretty good programmer and I have been working with Linux for 10+ years, but sometimes when trying to build programs from source I hit a brick wall. The current problem occurs when trying to build `vlc`, it claims that

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvorbisdec
```

This happens quite frequently. The first thing I do is try

```
sudo apt-get install vorbisdec
```

But that doesn't always [ever] work. Next I try googling it, but 99 times out of a hundred I get something like this

- vorbisdec...did you mean *vorbisenc*

I had a very similar problem tyring to install libgoom2. It doesn't help that sometimes the binaries you need (ie. goom) are in a preppended and appended file name (ie. xmms-libgoom2-dev)

Could someone fill in the missing step (s) with respect to how to properly go about installing programs from source:

1. `sudo apt-get install
2. ???
3. give up installing

Answer (score 6):

Most of libraries requested by ./configure can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install lib[library name]-dev
```

For example, vorbisdec is available in `libvorbis-dev` package. Sometimes you have to specify version number, like `libxcb-composite0-dev`, `liblua5.2-dev`, or if you don't know version number `libxcb-composite*-dev`. If `apt-get` still can't find requried packages, you have to compile them from source, and then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

**EDIT:** You can also use Tab button to list packages starting with libvorbis:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libvorbis[Tab]
libvorbis              libvorbisfile3         libvorbis-ocaml
libvorbis0a            libvorbisfile-ruby     libvorbis-ocaml-dev
libvorbis-dbg          libvorbisfile-ruby1.8  libvorbisspi-java
libvorbis-dev          libvorbisidec1         
libvorbisenc2          libvorbisidec-dev
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:** There is more :D

```
$ apt-cache search vorbis
libshout3 - MP3/Ogg Vorbis broadcast streaming library
libshout3-dev - MP3/Ogg Vorbis broadcast streaming library (development)
libtag1-dev - audio meta-data library - development files
libtag1-doc - audio meta-data library - API documentation
libtag1-vanilla - audio meta-data library - vanilla flavour
libtag1c2a - audio meta-data library
libtagc0 - audio meta-data library - C bindings
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve with

```
sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev
```